# largest product of 30 consecutive digits

Tags: java

I was given a programming question by a friend where I was given a 1000 character string of numbers. The task is to find the largest product of 30 consecutive digits.

Although my code looks right, the answer seems to come out really low, why is this?

The relevant code for this problem has been provided below.

```
  static String s = "2389748943892"; //... This number is actually 1000 characters.

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int largest = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 970; i  ) {
      String cur = s.substring(i, i 30);
      int cur_val = 0;
      for(int x = 0; x < 30; x  ) {
        if(x == 0) {
          System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(cur.substring(0, 1)));
          cur_val = Integer.parseInt(cur.substring(x, 1)); 
        } else {
          cur_val = cur_val * Integer.parseInt(cur.substring(x, x 1));
        }

      }
      if(cur_val > largest) {
        largest = cur_val;
      }
      System.out.println("Largest: "   largest);
      // should be 8876473335152640000 but is 2013265920

    }
  }
```

Comment: This code should print multiple times if it is correct and you are give a 1000 digit number. Is "2013265920" the only output?

Comment: Are you incrementing i by 1 or by 30? Is your question missing '+' characters?

Comment: Is your friend perhaps a teacher?  ;-)

Comment: Look at the max values of your variables.  You are trying to use an int to store a VERY large number and it is overflowing.  Try a LONG instead.

Comment: long is not sufficient either - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Arrgh, I read 'slow' instead of 'low'...
OK, forget about the performance issues, I thought you were speaking of.

Howver, long won't help you either: calculate ln(9^30)/ln(2), and you get little more than 95, thus you need 96 digits. Try Math.BigInteger then!

---

This is due to the excessive usage of substring (resulting in constructing and destroying new String objects all the time). As you are only interested in single characters, better use s.charAt(n). Parsing is then easy, too: Just subtract '0' from the char you got this way. So you get:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 970; ++i)
{
    int cur_val = 0;
    for(int x = i; x < i + 30; ++x)
    {
        cur_val *= s.charAt(x) - '0';
    }
}
/* rest as you had already */
```

(OK, I left out printing the substring).

Additionally, in the code you posted, there are some syntax errors (`substring i, i 30`, apparently there is missing a '+') and you did not increment the counter variables (if *this* happened in your code, too, you would have ended in endless loops - but then you would not have gotten a slow result, you would not have gotten any at all).

You might include some short cuts (e. g. if you find a '0' in the outer loop, you know that the result for the next 30 iterations will be 0 and you could skip these), giving you another speedup.

Comment: In the end, it was the use of int versus long that was causing the problem. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Read 'slow' instead of 'low' - sorry. Still, long won't help you out. See my new answer.